# How can i change YQL response language in my result?

Tags: response, yql

I'm using yahoo geocoding YQL to get the lan/lat for a list of places. This works, however the results are always retuned in english. However, would need the results in the local language (de-de for places in Germany, fr-fr for France etc.).

Here is my query:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+from+geo.placefinder+where+city%3D%27Dresden%27%20and%20country%20=%20%22Germany%22

Idealy it should return 'Deutschland' instead of 'Germany' here and 'Sachsen' instead of 'Saxony'. I tried adding 'lang' to the query as suggested on http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/web-services-http-responses.html, but that did not change anything.

Is there a way to switch the response languge? Even another webservice that supports this feature would be fine, i only need it once for ~2000 places.

Answer (score 1):

You must've tried `lang=de-DE` in your YQL call. The actual call would be
`select * from geo.placefinder where city='Dresden' and country = "Germany" and lang="de"`
Try it out at yql console [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+%2a+from+geo.placefinder+where+city=%27Dresden%27+and+country+=+%22Germany%22+and+lang=%22de%22). To read more about which locales are supported read [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/supported_locales.html).